# tensor conversion function numpy() doesn't work within tf.estimator model function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow2.0

I have tried this with both tensorflow v2.0 and v1.12.0 (with `tf.enable_eager_execution()` ). So apparently if I call `numpy()` with the code snippet shown below in my `main()` function, it works perfectly. However if I use it in my estimator model function i.e., `model_fn(features, labels, mode, params)` then it complains that `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`.

```
ndarray = np.ones([3, 3])
tensor = tf.multiply(ndarray, 42)
print(tensor)
print(tensor.numpy())
```

Has anyone else experienced similar problem? Seems like a big issue for tf.estimator no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work. Estimator API is tied to graph construction and it doesn't fully support eager execution. As per official documentation.

> Calling methods of Estimator will work while eager execution is
>   enabled. However, the model_fn and input_fn is not executed eagerly

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator

TF 2.0 won't even support custom estimators, only premade ones.

Comment: @Sharky "TF 2.0 won't even support custom estimators, only premade ones" 
Can you share your sources for this claim? I couldn't find any

Comment: It may've used not the exact right words, but afaik, custom model are kept only for backward compatibility. The recommended way is to use `keras.model_to_estimator` See https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/migration_guide#estimators